# How to fetch nvarchar(max) data from SQL Server with Poco?

Tags: sql, sql-server, poco-libraries

How can I fetch information from Microsoft SQL Server over an ODBC connection where the datatype is `nvarchar(max)` with [Poco libraries](https://pocoproject.org/)?

Example:

I have the following table in SQL Server 2019

```sql
create table test (
    id int primary key identity,
    name1 nvarchar(1024),
    name2 nvarchar(max)
);
```

I insert data into it as follows

```sql
insert into test (name1, name2)
  values ('Adam', 'Adam'),
         ('Bertha', 'Bertha'),
         ('Caesar', 'Caesar'),
         ('Diana', 'Diana');
```

`select * from test;` returns the following

```
id  name1   name2
--  -----   -----
1   Adam    Adam
2   Bertha  Bertha
3   Caesar  Caesar
4   Diana   Diana
```

Now I try to fetch the data in C++ with [Poco libraries](https://pocoproject.org/)

```cpp
Statement statement( session );
statement << "select * from test where id = 1;";
if ( statement.execute() > 0 ) {
    RecordSet recordSet = RecordSet( statement );
    recordSet.moveFirst();
    int id = recordSet.value( "id" );
    std::string name1 = recordSet.value( "name1" ).toString();
    std::string name2 = recordSet.value( "name2" ).toString();
}
```

And I get the following results: `id = 1`, `name1 = "Adam"`, `name2 = ""`.

Why do I get an empty string in the `name2` variable?
How can I retrieve the data in column *name2* with Poco?

Comment: Possibly, the limitation is that of the ODBC driver (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/features/using-large-value-types?view=sql-server-ver15#sql-server-native-client-odbc-driver). For `MAX` column lengths, the driver reports column length of 0. Try `Select CAST(name2 as ntext)` to convert from `NVARCHAR(MAX)` to `NTEXT` and see if that helps.

Comment: @basodre Thanks! Not really what I wanted to hear, because this makes things a lot more complicated for me, but your solution works. If you create an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Wait! `NTEXT` is [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx), so even if it works for now it's not a solution for the future.

Comment: Can you switch over to the OLE driver from ODBC? https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/b59ae1ba-1add-4a93-845e-e4505603d23f/selecting-varcharmax-or-nvarcharmax-columns-using-quotodbc-driver-11-for-sql-serverquot?forum=sqldataaccess